# Same asp.net sessionID across all users and sessions

Tags: c#, .net, session-variables

I'm testing a website which has the same asp.net sessionID for all users and sessions. There is another FedAuth cookie which is unique. But does that make it safer to use the same asp.net sessionID across board?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you like to share the session id between users? What's the story behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Same asp.net sessionID across all users and sessions  might be reason for Security vulnerability as  Session hijacking:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

Useful article for session management.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A2-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management

Session id might be stolen and using for attacking your system. Session storage should be always vanished after user log off.  FedAuth cookie  allows you to determine your users but the same session for all of them is not safe approach. You could use Application storage instead for this purposes.